# Complex factorisation of a psd matrix

Tags: matrix-decomposition

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix. Assume that $A=L\cdot L^{t}$ for $L\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times m}$. Can we infer that $L$ is intact real, i.e., has only real entries?

Comment: Note that we this does not hold one $A$ has not fall rank. For example $L=(2+I& 2-i)^t$ would yield a psd matrix, but the rank is not full.

Comment: Do you really mean to have transpose instead of conjugate transpose in your factorization of $A$?

Comment: Yes.. ätherweise it is clear...

Answer (score 1):

Let $L=\begin{pmatrix}i&\sqrt 2\\\sqrt 2&-i\end{pmatrix}$.
Then $LL'$ is the $2\times2$ identity matrix.